# Is there a way to create a layer with view over UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with some elements. I want to create a sublayer over that collection view, that will be scrolled according to the position of collection view and will cover only some elements of that. My point of creating sublayer is that, that will be dragable, so will be have ability to move despite of collection view position. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide a Visual Example or relevant code in question?

Comment: I only prepare simple collection view with elements and I stuck on that. I have a problem with creating sublayer, that will scroll with collection view. That's why I'm asked for some idea or help of structure of UIKit controls, how can I achieve that?